# Web Scrape returns N/A, not sure how to keep the data returning

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

totally new here & figured you guys will know the answer before I can even come near figuring this out.

I have a google form, feeding a live google sheet which users submit car reg numbers.

My goal is to have the reg number display the make, model besides the reg.

I have implemented an importXML function & the cell I expect to see the data loads up for a few minutes, then reverts to "N/A" or sometimes doesn't pull the data at all, but manually visiting the URL does return the data.

The import XML function uses a cell, made up of URL string, then adds the Reg/VIN input by form submission. That cell looks something like this "basicvehicledetails.com/reg" and returns the Class on the webpage relevant for Make/Model in separate cells.

I need the data to stay once it is returned, but don't know how to do that.

Another option is a car check website that requires a login, and then the reg to be input & searched before a webpage returns in-depth data on the car, is this something I can get to export to google sheet/excel spreadsheet?

I'm really stuck for this one, and would really appreciate any help as updating each car manually is painful.

Comment: whats the url/formula you use? also webscraping behind login is not possible in google sheets

Comment: So the formula is  =IMPORTXML(CC14,"//h4[@class='text-left vehicle-title float-left pl-1 col-8']") note that CC14 is the cell containing the URL (https://www.motorcheck.ie/free-car-check/?vrm=152D1234)

Comment: I also have a separate sheet using the same URL in C14 with to breakout make + model, then fuel type color etc - cell 1 is =IMPORTXML(C14,"//h4 [@class='text-left vehicle-title float-left pl-1 col-8']") cell2-4 is =IMPORTXML(C14,"//strong[@class='text-black weight-semibold']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.motorcheck.ie/free-car-check/?vrm=152D1234"),5000,1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'dark-left'", 0), "</?\S+[^<>]*>", )
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.cartell.ie/ssl/servlet/beginStarLookup?registration=152D1234",
 "table", 1)
```

[image: tive]

Comment: Wow, fixed. It also loads much quicker!!! Is there any way to do the same for the Fuel type & color? That just hangs on loading...

Comment: baby steps, sorry - I was born today :)

Comment: try: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.motorcheck.ie/free-car-check/?vrm=152D1234","//strong[@class='text-black weight-semibold']")`

Comment: or you could query it from source code: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.motorcheck.ie/free-car-check/?vrm=152D1234"),5000,10)`

Comment: example: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.motorcheck.ie/free-car-check/?vrm=152D1234"),5000,1), "where Col1 contains 'strong class'", 0), MOD(ROW(A1:A4), 2)=0), "</?\S+[^<>]*>", ))`

Comment: They are all going back to #N/A again.

Comment: I see, So would importData stay indefinitely or expire at some stage?

Comment: it reverts back to N/A, but how about this alternative: `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.cartell.ie/ssl/servlet/beginStarLookup?registration=152D1234", "table", 1)`

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try & see how it fairs out. thanks!